# How can i modifier a state only when has the same ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
editItem = (id) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        lanche: [
        {
          id: id,
          editItem: true
        }]
      }
    )
  }
```

In this way, setState runs on all items in the array, I need to edit only the item that has the same ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the item in the array with the given id, and modify that one only. setState method changes the whole object with the given key.

try this:

```
editItem = (id) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        lanche: this.state.lanche.map(item => {
           if(item.id === id) {
            item.editItem = true
           }
           return item;
        })
      }
    )
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map like this:

```
editItem = (id) => {
  // update the relevant item
  const updatedItems = this.state.lanche.map(item => {
    if (item.id === id) {
      item.editItem = true;
    }
    return item;
   } );

    this.setState(
      {
        lanche: updatedItems
      }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question;

You could search for the index like so;

```
const index = this.state.lanche.findIndex((e) => e.id === id);
```

and then alter the object

```
const newLanche = this.state.lanche;
newLanche[index].editItem = true;
```

And then update the store;

```
this.setState({ lanche: newLanche });
```